# Carpeta public de Laravel no me deja acceder a los recursos, alojada en Hostinger

Tags: laravel, hosting, https

tengo mi aplicación Laravel montada en Hostinger, sin embargo estoy intentando acceder a un recurso dentro de la carpeta `public`, es un archivo `JavaScipt`, esto por su puesto desde una `view` llamada `base.blade.php`

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

Cabe destacar que tengo `HTTPS` activado en mi sitio, y al cargar el contenido obtengo un status 404
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ruta del recurso esta en `public/assets/js/main.js`

He intentado modificar el `.htaccess`

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

# Allow Installatron requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} deleteme\.\w+\.php
RewriteRule (.*) - [L] 

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Tambien he visto que el problema puede estar alojado en el `public/index.php`
Especificamente en el apartado

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar esta condición para la carpeta assets.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/assets\/ [NC]
```

verifica que la URL solicitada no contiene "/assets/". Esto asegura que la regla se aplique solo si la solicitud no se dirige a los archivos en el directorio "/assets/".